# Spectral Networks and Deep Locally Connected Networks on Graphs

Tags: research, graph-neural-network

I’m reading the paper [Spectral Networks and Deep Locally Connected Networks on Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6203) and I’m having a hard time understanding the notation shown in the picture below (the scribbles are mine):
[image]

Specifically, I don’t understand the notation for the matrix F. Why does it include an i and a j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was curious, I found my answer in the Appendix in this paper, which explains the notation better: [Neural Message Passing for Quantum Chemistry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01212)

Answer (score 0):

`k` is a fixed parameter indicating the input layer and `i`,`j` refer to the index of the matrix F , used to traverse throught the matrix.

Comment: So I thought about that too, but then the summation goes up to $f_{k-1}$ (I.e the rows go up to this) yet they say that the matrix is $d_{k-1}$ by $d_{k-1}$.